# Where can I see which games are up for auction?

Tags: steam, steam-holiday-auction

According to the [steam holiday auction page](http://steamcommunity.com/auction), there are 100 copies each of almost 2000 games up for auction.  However, I only see 14 games listed on that page.  Where can I see all the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see - the Enhanced Steam plugin for Firefox breaks the page.

After disabling the plugins, I see the list of games [here](http://steamcommunity.com/auction).

Answer (score 2):

In the steam store click the banner on the top of the page then scroll down. You can use the buttons at the bottom of the list to see more games.